# c++ 11 Trailing return type with decltype does not work as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype, trailing-return-type

Why this works "as expected"?
My understanding is that this should not work:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto x(T a, U b) -> decltype(a<b ? a:b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}


int main() {
    cout << x<long, double>(1, 2.01) << endl;
    cout << x<long, double>(5, 2.01) << endl;

}
```

I have tried some other combinations such as:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto x(T a, U b) -> decltype(a<b ? a:a) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

This way it does not compile with error Actually the second combination fails with

```
compile time error:  Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'U' to 'T &'
```

which is expected. My understanding is that the first function also should fail with the same error, while it works fine.

Comment: What did you expect, what's the actual behavior, and in what way does it fail to meet your expectations? It's unclear to me what it is you are asking, exactly.

Comment: Like any expression, the expression `a<b ? a:b` has some type, derived from types of `a` and `b` and independent of their values. You seem to expect that the expression would have different types depending on whether, at run time, it turns out that `a<b` or `!(a<b)`. That ain't how C++ works - all types are determined at compile time.

Comment: Please be aware that the function has undefined behavior if it is called with two arguments of the same type. Don't use it. It would be fine if you removed the trailing `decltype(...)` return type or added a `std::decay_t` around it.

Comment: Actually the second combination fails with compile time error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'U' to 'T &'

Comment: My expectations are to see the max value printed out for various types, especially for double and long. But if you see in a decltype the min is written, while it still calculates the max.

Comment: As the condition in a decltype is inversed the return types are different so it would say compile time error or at least warning. While it returns the max.

Comment: Just did it, thank you.

Comment: @user2420079 "*My expectations are to see the max value printed out for various types*" - why are you not using `std::max()` for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the condition with the `?:` operator is. The result type is calculated as a *common type* of the second and third operand. Here is part of how the *common type* and the value category of the `?:` operator are calculated, see [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) for the full details:

If the second and third operand are lvalues of the same type, then the result type will be a lvalue of that type.

If the types are unrelated lvalues, there are some more complex rules to determine the common type, but the result will be a prvalue, not a lvalue. In particular if the two types are *arithmetic types* such as `double` and `long`, then the [*usual arithmetic conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#conversions) are applied to obtain a common type. In the case of `long` and `double` that common type would be `double`. This is the same type calculation that would be done if you e.g. tried to add two different arithmetic type with `+`, hence the name *usual arithmetic conversions*.

Therefore `decltype(a<b ? a:b)` will be a reference type if `a` and `b` have the same type and otherwise it will not be a reference type.

This is why the function compiles. The common type is always such that both input types can be converted to it. It is also why the function has undefined behavior if the types are equal, because then `decltype` gives a reference and so you are going to return a reference to one of the function parameters.

`decltype(a<b ? a:a)` doesn't work with different types, because the common type of `a` and `a` is, as described above, a reference of the type of `a`. If `b` then has a different unrelated type, the result of `a > b ? a : b` will be a prvalue which cannot be bound to a lvalue reference.

Comment: But in the case if it is not reference type we still will get the warning in case of double to long conversion, as the result should be integer while we see in output the double result which means that the reference has been passed or may be this is because of common type?

Comment: And also it is not very clear what is the common type. Could you please provide some more details about this as well?

Comment: @user2420079 The full (rather complicated) details are in the link I provided in the question. For two different arithmetic types, such as `long` and `double` the *usual arithmetic conversion* are applied to obtain a common type, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#conversions. In particular the common type of `long` and `double` is `double`. The `long` parameter would be converted to `double` if it is returned as the larger value.

Answer (score 1):

You may think that

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
auto x(T a, U b) -> decltype(a < b ? a : b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

std::cout << x<long, double>(1, 2.01) << std::endl;
std::cout << x<long, double>(5, 2.01) << std::endl;
```

won't compile because trailing return type `decltype(a < b ? a : b)`, i.e. inner expression `a < b ? a : b` is not the same as the return expression `a > b ? a : b` but this is perfectly legal because the return type becomes whatever type comes after the `->`.

Now, why the following code is not compiled successfully?

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
auto x(T a, U b) -> decltype(a < b ? a : a) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

std::cout << x<long, double>(1, 2.01) << std::endl;
std::cout << x<long, double>(5, 2.01) << std::endl;
```

It is because you need to remove the reference from the trailing return type, like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class U>
auto x(T a, U b) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(a < b ? a : a)>::type {
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}
```

Now it compiles successfully. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRAB2UgAdUCwuto9QxNBHz81Ohs7RyMXN14lFQjaBgJmYgIg41NzRMxVANT0giiHZ1cPRTSMrJDOKuLSmLiQbgBKRVQDYmQOAHIpAGZbZEMsAGpxQZ11BQJiTGYjKexxAAYAQSGRscxJ6YIATy9MAH155kIFFfWtzYJMIy9hB/2dUeYFBXGAFVJxj5fcYAVRum2YBiI4wAHhAfuNmP9geMnG1xgBaFbjI4nWhLPZzdAgEALIyoABuZwWVFcWl6Ux0WFGOMwEGYbxR%2BwAYgjxiAEW0VsSWZN3LJNuNJeMFgRurRxmz9thOVMeez%2BaipuKtu4ACK3W4PJ4vPYMwHfP4A4RA0GDVbgyGocaHOEIpEotGYu3Y45afHjQnE0kUqmYGkLWj06ZM1gsxUMlWDHlOPkCoUgEXiMW3KXSzCy4jy%2BPelOq3kawWDbVZ/WbW62AjjIyXWgQNFZ7W5wMoLqNhkJ6EM1h0YD/dBdJzsFYQerjSQAOjWnHb0wT3csrC1Oal3bQkLeA6HI7HE6ndogAFZ/gulyudGuCESQBut3WJTvH8S933V9NnUfRBPAxJ0wadZxvZcDz/ddtE3Ktt0lXdeygnR/2mYdAPGcdgLPbBL2vRdIP7aDP2fWDXzuDZcxlOVxjWCiaz6DpWBAPoLz6UhTD6NYONQVj7xkOQAy6HpTUkQZOA4ghWJ4toOgAaxAQYAA550kC9JE0wYAE4ADZdIvNY9O0oRWO4DiuJ40g%2BL6DiFBANZSGk7imNIOBYCQNAnjwdgyAoCAvK8HyKmAbTzCoHyHmIeyICcGSOKcWx0kOVjJNILyjC0AgAHlaFYFKXNILBm1Edh4qKvAFgKSl7MKzBoXySF%2BishtlHK1g8CcYhkr0LBUqk4g8CMfqOhoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFA5DkIROvsyAOlQLxklq9FCSmXUJEEmRODSvICg0CBLFqUx6ksJpyjceown8OgrtCXxntoO7YgqepTuSIoan0bJBD%2BwpqhKWwym%2Bh6GkB4JrthiHonurgOgUETelR0y2Is8qbOhZTdPRXTuHGYBkGQcZtLUhVcEIEhJnE2c9G83zGYktEBNkGQpPiuTSEUyRVO4HhuG4SR3DWJcL107TCex8zOLx1i7Icpy%2BbcmBEBAXsvEhchKEC4KYcwfAiBhsbGBYMrpoAd26rwRux9ilcKmyhk4cZbcIBAYUJ4nSfJynqckXmXP5xTBkGeco9juP44V3G3ZVxQ1ec2TmNY0PXasmyw4z0hKWigJWiAA)

The reason why the second example does not compile without `std::remove_reference` is because both types that are part of ternary operator are [`glvalue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)s and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) is said that:

> 4) If E2 and E3 are glvalues of the same type and the same value
>   category, then the result has the same type and value category

so the result of `a < b ? a : a` is a `glvalue`. That's why you need to remove the reference. And the result of `a < b ? a : b` is a `prvalue` and, therefore, you don't need to remove the reference.

Comment: The question is that in a first case we have exactly the same problem, because the instead of T it returns U& but it still compiles.